# How to set requests per second limit on GKE and Kong Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kong-ingress

I have a cluster on GKE and I want to set a limit for incoming requests, but I cannot find a way to do it using Kong Ingress Controller. I can't find any documentation or info about this specific topic.

Comment: I have never used Kong but [doc](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller#features) says you need a [plug in](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/).

Comment: I started my research [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191WWNpjJ2za6-nbG4ZoUMXMpUK8KlCIosvQB0f-oq3k/edit?fbclid=IwAR3pIpSh0A5yExTRP4J0yp-KMniw5DaDm-I3njCRl_QEqWJRLtBdOxtS2lU#gid=907731238), maybe it will help

Comment: Have a look at https://blog.baeke.info/2019/06/15/api-management-with-kong-ingress-controller-on-kubernetes/

Comment: @GariSingh thank you! The steps in this post fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps in this [article](https://blog.baeke.info/2019/06/15/api-management-with-kong-ingress-controller-on-kubernetes/), I achieved the desired results by adding the rate limit plugin in my kongo ingress. To do so, first, update / create your ingress definition and add the annotations defined below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: func
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong   # <-- THIS
    plugins.konghq.com: http-ratelimit  # <-- THIS
spec:
...
```

After, to finally set the rate-limit, use this definition and apply it in your kubernetes cluster:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: http-ratelimit
  namespace: default
config:
  policy: local
  second: 1
plugin: rate-limiting
```

This will create a restriction of 1 request per second in your ingress. If you want anything different, just change the config section with your own configuration. Check the plugin's [documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/) for all possible configurations.